# Why won't my filter logic work for this report

Tags: reporting

Filter Logic:

```
(1 AND 2 AND 3) AND (4 AND 5 AND 6)
```

Data shows when 1, 2 and 3 are on the report... but as soon as we add in 4 - there is no data.

1. Duration greater than "0"
2. Worksteps Name equals "provision services"
3. Status equals "open"
4. Worksteps Name equals "ACCEPT FACILITY"
5. Duration greater than "0"
6. Status equals "complete"

So essentially I need results when both 1,2,3 AND 4,5,6 are true.

Why is that? How can I fix it?

Comment: If you want 1,2,3 AND 4,5,6 to be true, why don't you just do `(1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 AND 5 AND  6)` as a whole? which means all 6 have to be true like you have stated.

Comment: You are describing an impossible circumstance. That's why your filter returns no records. Perhaps **[edit]** your post to include some expected data.

Comment: I believe you want the following `(1 AND 2 AND 3)` **OR** `(4 AND 5 AND 6)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to add custom logic when all of your operators are `AND`. That is the default logic.

Criteria `2` and `4` directly contradict each other. The `Worksteps Name` cannot possibly equal two distinct values at the same time. It seems likely what you really mean is:

```
1 AND (2 AND 3) OR (4 OR 6)
```

Note that `5` is redundant and not needed.

Comment: the workstep names are unique w/in a particular suborder (which is another value on the report outside of the filter criteria)... but I get what you are saying... perhaps the request is too complex. I can't see both 4 and 2 at the same time.

Comment: I updated to: 
Filter Logic: 1 AND (2 AND 3) or (4 and 5)

 
1. Duration greater than "0"
 
2. Worksteps Name equals "provision services"
 
3. Status equals "Open"
 
4. Worksteps Name equals "ACCEPT FACILITY"
 
5. Status equals "Complete"

Comment: That doesn't give me what I need... it really does need to be 2 and 3 AND 4 and 5

Comment: @Cora Surely you realize that it is impossible a single field to concurrently equal two different values?